# Binomial Distribution Question, Cannot figure out process

Tags: probability, combinations, binomial-distribution

I am really stuck on this question on my last homework and did not have time to stop by office hours. If anyone can walk me through this, I would really appreciate it.

> A marksman scores a bull's eye on 90% of his shots.
>
> a) What is the probability that he gets at least eight bull's eyes if he shoots ten times?
>
> b) If he shoots until he gets eight bull's eyes, what is the probability that he needs at most ten shots?

For part a) I did ${10\choose{8}}(.9)^8(.1)^2$. When worked through, I get .19371. I know the answer is .92981 for both questions but cannot figure out how to get there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You found the probability of exactly $8$, it asked for at least $8$

Comment: so would i have to find the probability of exactly 9 and 10. and then add those 3 probabilities together? @WaveX

Comment: Correct $$ $$ $$ $$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is the random variable corresponding to the number of successful shots, then $X \sim B(0.9,10)$.

For (a), we want to compute $P(X\ge 8)$ and can be done as follow, 
\begin{align}
P(X\ge8) &= P(X=8) + P(X=9) + P(X=10) \\ &= \binom{10}{8}(.9)^8(.1)^2 \binom{10}{9}(.9)^9(0.1) + \binom{10}{10}(0.9)^{10} \\ &= 0.9298092... 
\end{align}